# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'max_row'

Tags: openpyxl

```
os whidow7
python3.6
openpyxl 2.5.4
------------------------------------------------------------------
how to solve this problem?

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\updataProduce.py", line 22, in 
    countRow = sheet.max_row()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'max_row'

-----------------------------------------------------------
#! python3
# updataProduce.py - corrects costs in produce sales spreadsheet

from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook('produceSales.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active

# The produce types and their updated price
PRICE_UPDATES = {'Garlic': 3.07, 'Celery': 1.19, 'Lemon':1.27}

# TODO: loop through the rows and update the PRICE
countRow = sheet.max_row()
print(countRow)
for rowNum in range(2, countRow) :
    produceName = sheet.cell(row = rowNum, column = 1).value
    if produceName in PRICE_UPDATES:
        sheet.cell(row = rowNum, column = 2).value = PRICE_UPDATES[produceName]
wb.save('updateProduceSales.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#! python3
# updataProduce.py - corrects costs in produce sales spreadsheet

from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook('produceSales.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active

# The produce types and their updated price
PRICE_UPDATES = {'Garlic': 3.07, 'Celery': 1.19, 'Lemon':1.27}

# TODO: loop through the rows and update the PRICE
countRow = sheet.max_row
print(countRow)
for rowNum in range(2, countRow) :
    produceName = sheet.cell(row = rowNum, column = 1).value
    if produceName in PRICE_UPDATES:
        sheet.cell(row = rowNum, column = 2).value = PRICE_UPDATES[produceName]
wb.save('updateProduceSales.xlsx')
```

This should work for you now. The error message explains what the issue is:

`countRow = sheet.max_row()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'max_row'`

It is saying that the object does not have an attribute called max_row(). It does however have one called max_row. Simple mistake but your code is fine besides that.